# How do I see what requests from my AWS server look like on the other end of an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, request

I have an AWS server that I use to hit a public API, whose json responses I then parse in Python.
Is it possible to find out what my http requests to the API look like? I can always check /etc/hosts and everything but I'd like to see if I can construct an actual http request. I've only got CLI access to the AWS box so something like Fiddler or WireShark wouldn't work.

Comment: it's not clear what you are doing - if you are using the API then surely you know what the http requests look like?

Comment: I just call a urllib2.urlopen on the url, for instance http://mobile-api.hopper.com/api/v1/cards/trips?origin=airport%2FJFK&destination=airport%2FBKK&departure=2016-12-23&return=2017-01-06

Comment: Wireshark has a command line implementation, `tshark`.